# Various issues running valgrind from Qt Creator (infinite run, blank screen...)

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator, valgrind

So, I am having very weird issues when I run valgrind memcheck tool from Qt Creator.

First, changing the settings in Tools -> Options -> Analyzer -> Valgrind doesn't seem to change anything. For example, `Backtrace frame count` is initially set to 25 and when I change it to 20 or any other value, Qt Creator keeps running valgrind with `--num-callers=25`.

Second, when running Valgrind Memory Analyzer with my unit test project (which tests a library I wrote), I end up with an infinite run when I hit a test that verifies that starting a `QProcess` on a read-only script returns the intended error signal. To do so, my test tries to run a dummy script with read-only permission. In my class under test, I create a raw `QProcess` pointer and that pointer is cleaned up in the slot that is executed when the `QProcess::finished` signal is intercepted. My unit test program gets stuck when it reaches the `process->start(...)` instruction, valgrind indicates a memory leak and I have to abort it. I know that valgrind makes the program slower but I've tried waiting and it's just stucked. Note that if I explicitly `delete` my process right after the `start` instruction, the program runs to the end (but of course, my test fails because the process is deleted before it has a chance to try running the program and emit the `finished` signal reporting the error). When I add `process->waitForFinihed()` before I `delete` my process, I'm stuck again. So it seems to me that the `finished` signal is never emitted and that for some reason, even without `process->waitForFinihed()` the thread is stucked. Even when `waitForFinished()` timeout has been reached, it's still stucked.

My other weird issue is that when I run my QML application (that also uses my library), I get an empty white window. I spent some time tracking down the origin of the issue and here's what I discovered:

- I get a white window when I use an `InputPanel` **and** an `ApplicationWindow` **and** that my source code tries to register a type with `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<MyClass>(...)`
- If I remove the `InputPanel` **or** use `Window` instead of `ApplicationWindow` **or** do not register my classes, it works.
- Actually, I don't even need to execute `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<MyClass>(...)`. Just having this code in my source causes the issue.
- `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<MyClass>(...)` does not cause the issue anymore if `MyClass` belongs to my UI project. It only occurs if `MyClass` is from my library.
- Exploring the implementation of that function, I could narrow the problem down to the use of the static member `QObject::staticMetaObject`. Accessing the meta-object for a class from my library seems to be causing the issue for some reason.

It just doesn't make much sense to me. I can't connect the dots between all those weird bugs.
Also, **running valgrind from the terminal does not cause any of these issues**. I considered using valgrind from my terminal rather than Qt Creator but I the end up with dozens of issues from external libraries (Qt and/or libraries used by Qt and maybe my testing framework). I can't find my own issues in that mess. Qt Creator allows to hide these error by unticking the `External Errors` checkbox, which is very convenient. I couldn't manage to have a clearer output when using valgrind from my terminal, I read about using a suppression file but the process seemed very cumbersome. Maybe those issues I mentioned with Qt Creator are just bugs from the IDE and using valgrind from my terminal would be the solution? But then, how to conveniently get rid of all the valgrind errors from external libraries?

I hope you can help me either fix valgrind from Qt Creator or use it from my terminal while hiding all these errors I'm not interested in. Thank you.

**EDIT**: I am running Qt Creator 4.14.1 on Ubuntu 20.04, running in a VirtualBox VM. Valgrind version is 3.15.

Comment: What OS? What hardware? Which versions of Qt Creator and Valgrind?

Comment: I am running Qt Creator 4.14.1 on Ubuntu 20.04, running in a VirtualBox VM. Valgrind version is 3.15

Comment: OK. 3.15 is a little bit old, but not too bad. I'll see if I can reproduce anything.